# Symfony 5.4 Webpack Encore server dev

Tags: symfony, webpack-dev-server, webpack-encore

I have a problem with Symfony 5.4 and WebPack yet.
when I want to run the npm run dev-server this one tells me:

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:3000/, http://127.0.0.1:3000/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'F:\Symfo\api-2021\public' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2064ms
```

and on the page (localhost or 127.0.0.1) I have Cannot GET / and nothing in the console except that I am missing the favicon

my version of npm is: 8.1.2

my webpack.config.js

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    .enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

EDIT

this is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class AppController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('app/index.html.twig', [
            
        ]);
    }
}
```

The template app/index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello AppController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

and the base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` to start using Symfony UX #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and the app.js

```
import './styles/app.css';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';

console.log('test')
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you show us how you integrated your own JS or CSS files into the template, which is rendered when the route is called?

Comment: Yes, this is the start of my site, I edit the first post

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: how are you resolved tthis error?